# Converting PNG files to GeoTIFF using Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, convert, rasterio, png

I have a big set of PNG files and EPSG:3006 coordinates of the edges of each file. (actually the coordinates of the edges are given in the file name, like this: *'image_666751_7023263_667007_7023519.png'*, so 666751, 7023263, 667007, 7023519 are the boundaries of the this image in EPSG:3006 )

How can I convert those PNG files to GeoTIFF files using Python so the TIFF files would contain the geo metadata.
I guess it can be done with Rasterio lib, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 7):

eventually this worked for me:

```
dataset = rasterio.open(input_file_path, 'r')
bands = [1, 2, 3]
data = dataset.read(bands)
transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, data.shape[1], data.shape[2])
crs = {'init': 'epsg:3006'}

with rasterio.open(output_file_path, 'w', driver='GTiff',
                   width=data.shape[1], height=data.shape[2],
                   count=3, dtype=data.dtype, nodata=0,
                   transform=transform, crs=crs) as dst:
    dst.write(data, indexes=bands)
```

Comment: Can you write the Full code below for better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) that is part of the GDAL library. There are Python bindings available through the [osgeo package](https://gdal.org/python/).

This is untested, but it should get you close to what you need:

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.Warp(
  dstDS,
  srcDS,
  format='GTiff',
  dstSRS='EPSG:3006',
  outputBounds=[minX, minY, maxX, maxY]
)
```

You'll need to define the source and destination datasets, and fill in the extent for *outputBounds*. You can find more examples in the [GDAL test suite](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py).

Comment: this won't work, you need GPCs for that